# Jquery-ui tabs and history

Tags: jquery-ui, backbone.js

I'm using backbone.js with jquery-ui tabs and my browser's back button is working fine. However, I would like to dynamically add and remove tabs and reverse those actions via back button. For example if the following happens:

```
#tab-1
#tab-2
open tab-3
#tab-3
```

When I click in the back button, the following should happen:

```
close tab-3 and go to #tab-2
#tab-1
```

What is the best solution for this?
Thanks

Comment: Well this is gonna seem obvious, but why don't you close tab-3 and open tab-2?
You'll have to give a whole lot more details for us to help you on this. What is not working for you right now?

Comment: After I have opened a tab using jquery-ui (http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#manipulation) when I click on the browser "back" button I wish the tab was closed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue as you a few months back.  I originally used jQuery-UI tabs on a project, https://www.implantlink.com/ but as the app grew, the friction between tabs and backbone proved too annoying and limiting.  After all the hardship of trying to get jQuery-UI tabs and Backbone to play nice, I can tell you it's just not worth it.

You may be better off abandoning jQuery-UI tabs and sticking entirely with backbone.js if your project is complicated enough.  Copy all the necessary CSS & HTML you need to create your own tabs, then setup each tab as a route and callback function to switch out your HTML.

**Example Tabs**

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a>
    <li><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a>
    <li><a href="#tab3">Tab 3</a>
</ul>
```

**Example JS**

```
$('#content').html('tab 2 HTML and content stuff');
```